# New Plug-In Project Wizard, why is "this plugin will make contributions to the ui" disabled?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to create a new Plug-In Project in Eclipse.
For some reason the checkbox "this plugin will make contributions to the ui" is disabled.
[image]

The Eclipse installation itself can't be the problem, using the same installation in other workspaces the checkbox is active.
So I suspect the target definition, missing some unit:

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.5.2.M20160212-1500"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.sdk.id" version="4.5.2.M20160212-1500"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.5.2.M20160212-1500"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/"/>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that I selected "an OSGi Framework" instead of a "Eclipse version" on the first wizard page:

[image]

Switching to "Eclipse version" enables the checkbox.
Makes sense since the generated activator extends "org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin" which is an eclipse class.
Also the option to create a "Rich Client Application" is enabled.